# ListView with onItemClick position

Tags: java, android, listview

I got an App with ListView and on any row you click it's popup something different.(With PauseDialog). And the headers in any row is in a "array.xml" and the text that will popup in the PauseDialog is in the java code.
the problem is that i need to add a lot of rows to the ListView and i want to know if there is way more efficacious to do it than what i did.
Example of the array.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
        <array name="Row_List">  
            <item>row1</item>
            <item>row2</item>
            <item>row3</item>
            <item>row4</item>
    </array>   
</resources>
```

(just a lot more rows...)
the java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptr;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adaptr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
                         , getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Row_List));
            View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        list.addHeaderView(header);
        list.setAdapter(adaptr);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        list.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    }
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(this, R.style.PauseDialog);
        dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.dialog1);
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        dialog1.setTitle(R.string.Title);
        dialog1.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        switch(position) {
        case 0:
            String url = "My-Site.com";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 1:
            text.setText("Description of Row1");
            dialog1.show();
            break;
        case 2:
            text.setText("Description of Row2");
            dialog1.show();
            break;
        case 3:
            text.setText("Description of Row3");
            dialog1.show();
            break;
        case 4:
            text.setText("Description of Row4");
            dialog1.show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So there is a better way to put the description into the dialog?(and i would like if there is a way the all the descriptions will be in a xml file and not in the code)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your descriptions as a `string-array` in `arrays.xml`:

```
<string-array name="desciptions">
    <item>item 0 descript</item>
    <item>item 1 descript</item>
    <item>item 2 descript</item>
</string-array>
```

.. define an array MainActivity:

```
static String[] desciptions = null;
```

.. initialize it in onCreate():

```
if (null==desciptions) desciptions
  = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);
```

.. and replace your switch statement with something like this, accounting for your '0' special case:

```
if (0==position) {
    String url = "My-Site.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
} else {
    text.setText(descriptions[position]);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Just keep in mind you need to make allowances for your special `0` case, to keep your indexes aligned, such as using `text.setText(descriptions[position-1]);` or having an empty item 0 description.

Comment: and if i want to make it static?

Comment: Assuming 'it' is the `descriptions` array (since I'd highly recommend it) I updated my answer. Please let me know if you meant something else.